# How to find maximal eulerian subgraph?

Tags: graph-algorithm, graph-theory, cycle, subgraph

How to find maximal eulerian subgraph of a given graph? By "maximal" I mean subgraph with maximal number of edges, vertices, or both. My idea is to find basis of cycle space and combine basis cycles in a proper way, but I don't know how to do it (and is it a good idea or not).

**UPD.** Source graph is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts. Graph is eulerian iff it is connected (with possible isolated vertices) and all vertices have even degree.

It is 'easy' to satisfy second criteria by removing (shortest) paths between pairs of odd degree vertices.

Connectivity is problematic since removing edges can produce unconnected graph.

An example which shows that 'simple' (greedy) solution is not easy to produce. Modify complete graph K5 by splitting each edge in two edges (or more). Take two these modified K5 graph and from each one take two vertices (A, B from first and C, D from second). Connect A-C and B-D. Greedy approach would remove these added edges since they are the shortest paths. With that graph becomes unconnected. Solution would be to remove paths A-B and C-D.

It seems to me that algorithm should take a care about subgraph connectivity while removing edges. For sure algorithm should preserve that each subset of odd degree vertices, of which no pair are used to remove path between them, should have connectivity larger than cardinality of subset.

I would try (for a test) with recursive brute force solution with optimization. O is list of odd degree vertices.

```
def remove_edges(O, G):
  if O is empty:
    return solution
  for f in O:
    for t in O\{f}":
      G2 = G without path edges between (f,t)
      if G2 is unconnected:
        continue
      return remove_edges(O\{f,t}, G2)
```

Optimization can be to order sets O and O{f} by vertices that have shortest paths. That can be done by finding shortest lengths between all pairs of vertices from O before removing edges. That can be done by BFS from each O vertex.

Answer (score 2):

It is proved in 1979 that determining if a given graph contains a spanning Eulerian subgraph is NP-complete.
Ref: W. R. Pulleyblank, A note on graphs spanned by
Eulerian graphs, J. Graph Theory 3, 1979, pp.
309–310,

Please refer to [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-018-1992-7#:%7E:text=A%20spanning%20subgraph%20of%20a,has%20a%20spanning%20Eulerian%20subgraph.)

Finding the maximum size (number of edges) of spanning Eulerian subgraph of a graph (if it exists) is an active research area.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following standard definitions. Given a graph G = (V, E)

- A *circuit* is a sequence of adjacent vertices starting and ending at
  the same vertex. Circuits do not allow repeated edges but they do allow
  repeated vertices.
- A *cycle* is a special case of a circuit in which vertices also do not
  repeat.

[image: Example Cycle and circuit]

Note that circuits and Eulerian subgraphs are the same thing. This means that finding the *longest circuit* in G is equivalent to finding a maximum Eulerian subgraph of G. As noted above, this problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). So, unless P=NP, an efficient (i.e. polynomial time) algorithm for finding a maximal Eulerian subgraph in an arbitrary graph is impossible.

For undirected graphs, one way of randomly producing an Eulerian subgraph is to identify a [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis) for G. A cycle basis is a set of cycles that, when combined using symmetric differences, can be used to form every Eulerian subgraph of the original graph G. Hence, we only need to take a random selection of cycles from this set and combine them to get our arbitrary Eulerian subgraph.

Given that an Eulerian subgraph is basically a collection of overlapping cycles, here is a greedy, polynomial-time algorithm that I'd like to suggest for finding large (but not necessarily maximum) Eulerian subgraphs. This works for both directed and undirected graphs and produces a set of edges (or arcs) E’ that define an Eulerian subgraph containing a user-defined source vertex s. The following steps are for directed graphs but can be easily modified for the undirected case.

```
Let U = {s} and E' = {}
while U is not empty
   Let u be a random element in U
   Form a cycle C from u in G
   if no such cycle C exists
      Remove u from U
   else
      Add the arcs of C to E'
      Remove the arcs of C from G
      Add the vertices of C to U
```

Here’s a few points to note about this algorithm.

1. Here, the set U holds the vertices that are yet to be fully considered by the algorithm.
2. To apply this method to undirected graphs, just replace the word
   "arcs" with "edges"
3. This method can be seen as a generalisation of
   [Hierholzer's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer%27s_algorithm). Hence, if the input graph G is already
   an Eulerian graph, then the returned set E’ will contain all of the
   edges from G.
4. Various methods can be used to generate a cycle C from
   vertex u. For directed graphs, a simple method is to create an
   additional dummy vertex u' and temporarily redirect all of the incoming arcs
   from u to u'. Various algorithms can then be used to determine a
   u-u'-path (which represents a cycle), such as [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), or
   [Wilson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk).

This algorithm can be said to produce a *maximal* Eulerian subgraph with respect to G and s. This is because, on termination, no further cycles can be added to the solution contained in E'. Note that we should not confuse the terms *maximal* and *maximum* here: finding a *maximal* Eulerian subgraph is easy (using the above method); finding a *maximum* Eulerian subgraph is NP-hard. Similar terminology is used with [matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximal_matchings).